# Where and how to store images when using Glide in Android with a Client/Server architecture

Tags: android, client-server, android-glide

I am currently implementing an application for a ordering system in a restaurant. I have multiple clients that can view the menu (with images) and one server. All devices are tablets. Now I would like to use Glide to load the images from the server to the clients. The images should be stored in the server (tablet). Now I have questions about this:

1. Is it possible to store the images on the server tablet such that the tablet itself is the server or do I need another external device as the servers?
2. How can the images be stored in the server such that they can be requested from other devices? Normally when using Glide you provide an URL as far as I know. So each image should have a URL that servers as the link for Glide to this image. What do I have to do in order to make this possible.

I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thankful if you could share your experiences.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to avoid making callback with the server instead storing the image as local?

Comment: Thanks Ticherhaz for your comment. Basically I have a lot of images and when I store them locally I often read that this is not a good idea and that one should rather use something like Glide to load the images. This is why I think it will be better when they are storead in a server. Don't you agree on that?

Comment: You better let the clients download the images from the server. Glide not needed to place a bitmap in an image view.

Comment: You also could adapt your server with nanohttpd. Then you can keep Glide and a http url.

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your answer. What do I have to do in order to make the tablet function as a server? Can I just store the images on the tablet and somehow make them accessible via an URL?

Comment: And do I understand you correctly that I should not use Glide (or something similar) for accessing pictures in Android? This would surprise me as a huge numer of people (also here on Stackoverflow) have strongly advised me to use Glide and I read quite often that it is beneficial to use something like this (altough I never really understood the reasons)

Comment: @blackapps: Thanks for your comments. Any comments to my last comments? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: If Glide needs an url and if you tell that you dont have an url... then you can conclude for yourself i would say. But using nanohttp you would have an url. So.. Conclude..  And you can store images on a tablet as on every Android device.

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Well, basically I still have 2 questions to you. 1) How can I make a server out of the tablet that can be used for stroring images via an URL? Is this possible with nanohttp? Or what else woud you advice me to use? 2) Generally would you not recommend using Glide - or something similar - for displaying images in Android apps (I ask that because many others strongly adviced me to use it)? I'd highly appreciate your opinion on those questions.

Comment: @blackapps: Thanks for your answer and effort. Any comments to my last comment? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: I already said everything. You only ask for the same.